# How to write an testcase for $interval in karma along with promises?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, setinterval, karma-jasmine, testcase

I am very new to Karma test cases and it seems to be a tricky and challenging task to write an test case for my mock up result:

My Service function looks like this and its working fine:

```
var api = new Api(xyz);
        // maxTimer is 5 minutes
        var maxTimer = 1000 * 60 * 5;
        var dataSearchTimeout = maxTimer;
        var delayCall = 2000;
        var data, dataSearch;

function getResults(id, prevDeferred) {
            var deferred = prevDeferred || $q.defer();

            function stopGettingSizingResults() {
                $interval.cancel(dataSearch);
                dataSearch = undefined;
                dataSearchTimeout = maxTimer;
            }

            function handleSuccessResponse(data) {
                if (data.status === CONSTANT.STATUS.READY) {
                    stopGettingResults();
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                } else {
                    if (!dataSearch) {
                        dataSearch = $interval(function () {
                            getResults(id, deferred);
                        }, delayCall);
                    }

                    dataSearchTimeout = dataSearchTimeout - delayCall;

                    if (dataSearchTimeout <= 0) {
                        stopGettingResults();
                        handleErrorResponse();
                    }
                }
            }

            function handleErrorResponse(response) {
                deferred.reject(response);
            }

            api.get({'id': id}).then(handleSuccessResponse, handleErrorResponse);

            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

I am playing for no results by updating the mockup data to 'Not Ready' and that is checking up with this condition `data.status === CONSTANT.STATUS.READY` and keeps on checking for 5 minutes as declared here: `var maxTimer = 1000 * 60 * 5;` and successfully throws error.

I am facing challenge to simulate the same from Karma test case:

I tried writing this and I am stuck and not able to proceed further:

```
it('should throw error timeout happens', inject(function(CONSTANT, $httpBackend, $q) {
            var results = {status: 'Not Ready'};
            CONSTANT.maxTimer = 100 * 60 * 5;
            $httpBackend.expectGET(apicall).respond(results);
        }));
```

It would be a great help if this can be continued, so that I can learn as well.

Comment: `ng-mock` adds a `flush(n)` method to `$interval` that you can use to purge specific timers.

Comment: thanks @JoeyCiechanowicz can you please elaborate a bit and thats a service call.

Comment: if you call `$interval.flush(n)` in your test, it will complete all intervals you have in your code of length `n`.